# Role duplication and execution only works on first role entry

Tags: ansible

Disclaimer ... I am new to Ansible but after a few days of googling and trying different things I am struggling with a seemingly basic problem. Below I have put my playbooks and the job runs fine but only the first role actually executes with the variable. Any help in this is greatly appreciated.

```
---
- connection: local
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - role: slb
      vars:
           name: "test1"
    - { role: slb, vars: { name: "test2" }}
    - { role: slb, vars: { name: "test3" }}
```

The folder structure is then roles/slb/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: create virtual server
   a10_slb_virtual_server:
     a10_host: "10.247.5.29"
     a10_username: "xxxxx"
     a10_password: "xxx"
     a10_port: "443"
     a10_protocol: "https"
     name: " {{ name }} "
     ip_address: "10.1.1.1"
     netmask: "255.255.255.0"
     port_list:
     - port_number: 80
       protocol: tcp
     enable_disable_action: enable
     stats_data_action: stats-data-enable
```

Edit - here is a code example that works using the same syntax so maybe it is an issue with the module?

```
---
- connection: local
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
  - role: text
    vars:
         name: "Scooby"
  - { role: text, vars: { name: "Shaggy" }}



- name: Create a text file
  file:
    path: "/var/lib/awx/projects/test/{{ name }}.txt"
    state: touch


'''
[root@awx-ansible a10]# ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml -vvvv
ansible-playbook 2.8.4
  config file = /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules/a10_ansible/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
script declined parsing /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/hosts as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.pyc

PLAYBOOK: main.yml ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Positional arguments: main.yml
become_method: sudo
inventory: (u'/var/lib/awx/projects/a10/hosts',)
forks: 5
tags: (u'all',)
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
timeout: 10
1 plays in main.yml
[WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: name


PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [slb : create] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/roles/slb/tasks/main.yml:3
<10.247.5.29> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014930.09-177848662916729 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1572014930.09-177848662916729="`
echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014930.09-177848662916729 `" ) && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.5'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules/a10_ansible/library/a10_slb_virtual_server.py
<10.247.5.29> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-57176X2vg1j/tmp5QQ2WF TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014930.09-177848662916729/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014930.09-177848662916729/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014930.09-177848662916729/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014930.09-177848662916729/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014930.09-177848662916729/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [10.247.5.29] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "a10_host": "10.247.5.29",
            "a10_partition": null,
            "a10_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "a10_port": 443,
            "a10_protocol": "https",
            "a10_username": "admin",
            "acl_id": null,
            "acl_id_shared": null,
            "acl_name": null,
            "acl_name_shared": null,
            "arp_disable": null,
            "description": null,
            "disable_vip_adv": null,
            "enable_disable_action": "enable",
            "ethernet": null,
            "extended_stats": null,
            "get_type": null,
            "ha_dynamic": null,
            "ip_address": "10.1.1.1",
            "ipv6_acl": null,
            "ipv6_acl_shared": null,
            "ipv6_address": null,
            "migrate_vip": null,
            "name": " test1 ",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
            "port_list": [
                {
                    "port_number": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "redistribute_route_map": null,
            "redistribution_flagged": null,
            "shared_partition_policy_template": null,
            "state": "present",
            "stats_data_action": "stats-data-enable",
            "template_logging": null,
            "template_policy": null,
            "template_policy_shared": null,
            "template_scaleout": null,
            "template_virtual_server": null,
            "use_if_ip": null,
            "user_tag": null,
            "uuid": null,
            "vport_disable_action": null,
            "vrid": null
        }
    },
    "message": "",
    "original_message": "",
    "result": {},
    "virtual-server": {
        "a10-url": "/axapi/v3/slb/virtual-server/%20test1%20",
        "arp-disable": 0,
        "disable-vip-adv": 0,
        "enable-disable-action": "enable",
        "extended-stats": 0,
        "ip-address": "10.1.1.1",
        "name": " test1 ",
        "netmask": "/24",
        "port-list": [
            {
                "a10-url": "/axapi/v3/slb/virtual-server/%20test1%20/port/80+tcp",
                "action": "enable",
                "auto": 0,
                "clientip-sticky-nat": 0,
                "conn-limit": 64000000,
                "cpu-compute": 0,
                "def-selection-if-pref-failed": "def-selection-if-pref-failed",
                "extended-stats": 0,
                "force-routing-mode": 0,
                "ha-conn-mirror": 0,
                "ipinip": 0,
                "memory-compute": 0,
                "message-switching": 0,
                "no-auto-up-on-aflex": 0,
                "no-dest-nat": 0,
                "no-logging": 0,
                "port-number": 80,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "range": 0,
                "reset": 0,
                "reset-on-server-selection-fail": 0,
                "rtp-sip-call-id-match": 0,
                "scaleout-bucket-count": 32,
                "skip-rev-hash": 0,
                "snat-on-vip": 0,
                "stats-data-action": "stats-data-enable",
                "syn-cookie": 0,
                "template-tcp": "default",
                "template-virtual-port": "default",
                "use-alternate-port": 0,
                "use-default-if-no-server": 0,
                "use-rcv-hop-for-resp": 0,
                "uuid": "0c2a963c-f741-11e9-b845-e9b0dd63a720"
            }
        ],
        "redistribution-flagged": 0,
        "stats-data-action": "stats-data-enable",
        "uuid": "0c2a19e6-f741-11e9-b845-e9b0dd63a720"
    }
}

TASK [slb : create] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/roles/slb/tasks/main.yml:3
<10.247.5.29> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014931.51-10342010886567 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1572014931.51-10342010886567="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014931.51-10342010886567 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules/a10_ansible/library/a10_slb_virtual_server.py
<10.247.5.29> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-57176X2vg1j/tmpKJVm5x TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014931.51-10342010886567/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014931.51-10342010886567/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014931.51-10342010886567/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014931.51-10342010886567/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014931.51-10342010886567/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [10.247.5.29] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "a10_host": "10.247.5.29",
            "a10_partition": null,
            "a10_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "a10_port": 443,
            "a10_protocol": "https",
            "a10_username": "admin",
            "acl_id": null,
            "acl_id_shared": null,
            "acl_name": null,
            "acl_name_shared": null,
            "arp_disable": null,
            "description": null,
            "disable_vip_adv": null,
            "enable_disable_action": "enable",
            "ethernet": null,
            "extended_stats": null,
            "get_type": null,
            "ha_dynamic": null,
            "ip_address": "10.1.1.1",
            "ipv6_acl": null,
            "ipv6_acl_shared": null,
            "ipv6_address": null,
            "migrate_vip": null,
            "name": " test2 ",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
            "port_list": [
                {
                    "port_number": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
           ],
            "redistribute_route_map": null,
            "redistribution_flagged": null,
            "shared_partition_policy_template": null,
            "state": "present",
            "stats_data_action": "stats-data-enable",
            "template_logging": null,
            "template_policy": null,
            "template_policy_shared": null,
            "template_scaleout": null,
            "template_virtual_server": null,
            "use_if_ip": null,
            "user_tag": null,
            "uuid": null,
            "vport_disable_action": null,
            "vrid": null
        }
    },
    "message": "",
    "original_message": "",
    "result": {}
}

TASK [slb : create] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /var/lib/awx/projects/a10/roles/slb/tasks/main.yml:3
<10.247.5.29> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014932.64-244561048768912 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1572014932.64-244561048768912="`
echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014932.64-244561048768912 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules/a10_ansible/library/a10_slb_virtual_server.py
<10.247.5.29> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-57176X2vg1j/tmpuWRYRS TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014932.64-244561048768912/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014932.64-244561048768912/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014932.64-244561048768912/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014932.64-244561048768912/AnsiballZ_a10_slb_virtual_server.py && sleep 0'
<10.247.5.29> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572014932.64-244561048768912/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [10.247.5.29] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "a10_host": "10.247.5.29",
            "a10_partition": null,
            "a10_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "a10_port": 443,
            "a10_protocol": "https",
            "a10_username": "admin",
            "acl_id": null,
            "acl_id_shared": null,
            "acl_name": null,
            "acl_name_shared": null,
            "arp_disable": null,
            "description": null,
            "disable_vip_adv": null,
            "enable_disable_action": "enable",
            "ethernet": null,
            "extended_stats": null,
            "get_type": null,
            "ha_dynamic": null,
            "ip_address": "10.1.1.1",
            "ipv6_acl": null,
            "ipv6_acl_shared": null,
            "ipv6_address": null,
            "migrate_vip": null,
            "name": " test3 ",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
            "port_list": [
                {
                    "port_number": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "redistribute_route_map": null,
            "redistribution_flagged": null,
            "shared_partition_policy_template": null,
            "state": "present",
            "stats_data_action": "stats-data-enable",
            "template_logging": null,
            "template_policy": null,
            "template_policy_shared": null,
            "template_scaleout": null,
            "template_virtual_server": null,
            "use_if_ip": null,
            "user_tag": null,
            "uuid": null,
            "vport_disable_action": null,
            "vrid": null
        }
    },
    "message": "",
    "original_message": "",
    "result": {}
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.247.5.29                : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
'''
```

Comment: What happens if you run the role without setting `name` ? does it still have a value ? If yes, where is that value taken from ? Please provide a full [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) based on debug action to reproduce (or not....) the current situation. If need be, have a look at [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) in ansible.

Comment: Name and ip_address are required by the module to run so it fails without setting name. I am following the Ansible doc on "Role Duplication and Execution" and the job runs but only the first entry "test1" is created. According to the Ansible docs if the variables are different then the role will be run again which is what the verbose output implies but nothing actually happens. Thanks for the help in this.

Comment: @gtrimbach Could you please attach the complete ansible output in the question. As I am able to run my role having a debug task to print the name using a similar ansible main playbook and it works absolutely fine. FYI my ansible version is 2.8, what's your ansible version?

Comment: I added the output Shubham ... are you also using the A10 module in your environment? Thanks to you and Zeitounator for the help in this.

Answer (score 0):

After much work I was able to resolve my issue by starting from scratch and it appears that the original problem was caused by spaces in the play variable " {{ name }} ". Once I changed it to "{{ name }}" things seemed to work as expected. I'm still struggling with the syntax but once I got this working I've been able to really tie plays together as I had hoped. Thanks to both of you for the help.